# Change Gmail API Name on Login Screen

Tags: api, gmail

I made a script using Gmail API to get list of contacts. The script working fine but I want to make it more better as for now, when Login POPUP of Gmail is opened it displays this

```
xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com is requesting permission to:

    Manage your contacts
```

Where xxxxxxxxxx is my Client ID. I dont want it to be shown. I want to display my API Project Name here like this

```
"My API Name" is requesting permission to:

    Manage your contacts
```

Is this even possible to do this? If yes then how?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this out:

1. Search for "Google API Console" in the browser.
2. On the API console page, on the left hand side menu bar, under "APIs & auth", click on "Consent Screen".  Setup project name, upload logo, etc.
3. See if this helps.
4. I also seem to remember that during oAuth, you need to pass Application Name (which can be the same as Product Name found in Consent Screen option at step 2 above.